# Rewriting a high-order nonlinear ODE as a system of first-order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have the following nonlinear ODE:

$$
(\frac{d^3 y}{dx^3})^2 - 2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx} - y^3 = 0,
$$

and would like to convert it to a system of first-order ODEs. Here's how I'm approaching the problem:

Let $x_1 = y$, $x_2 = y'$, and $x_3 = y''$, so we get $x_1 ' = x_2$ and $x_2 ' = x_3$. For the third equation, I get:

$$
x_3 ' = \pm \sqrt{x_1 ^3 + x_2 + 2x_3}.
$$

My question is: how do I determine the sign of the square root? Can it even be determined? What does this mean in terms of uniqueness of the solution of the ODE?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It means you will have two possible ODEs, neither of which are Lipschitz because of the square root (unless you can justify ahead of time why you would avoid $x_3' = 0$ for all time). This sort of thing shows quite often in the analysis of the Friedmann equation which describes the expansion of the universe.

Comment: The problem with the square root has nothing to do with the rewriting as a first order system.

Comment: Just leave it as $(x_3 ')^2 = x_1 ^3 + x_2 + 2x_3$. The equation is not explicit and that's not much you can do. Even for the original 3rd order equation you face the same problem.